# Can't login to admin account on Windows 7. Xpsl701x

Tags: administrator

How do I gain admin control? I can't change anything the admin account the admin account has a password I guess. It's the Windows administrative password but I'm just really stuck and confused because I've got two logins: one is Tony ones Tony admin. I can log in under Tony but I can't change anything I can't log under Tony admin because there's a password.

Comment: Use Pogo Stick (https://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/) Use RUFUS to make a bootable USB Key and reset the Administrator Password.

Answer (score -1):

There are tools that you can use to change or delete windows passwords.  Most of these tools install onto a usb drive, boot into a shell and include software to change or delete windows accounts by editing the registry.  Hiren's boot cd comes to mind, and has many other tools to fix windows machines besides resetting passwords.  You can find instructions on how to do this on the web.  Try to find a reputable tool without malware by downloading from a site you can trust.  This will work on a Win7 machine; have not tried this on a Win10 secure boot machine.

Comment: Those tools are unnecessary.  See the duplicate.